# In Jmeter, i want 50 users(from csv) to login every 2 hours for 24 hours, how can i do it ? i am new to jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load, load-testing

I have a csv file with say 500 users details (id, pwd)
i want 50 users to login every 2 hours
for ex , at morning 8 am 50 users should login, at 10 am 50, 12 pm - 50 users and so on
please help in details i am complete newbie

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1uaZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [custom thread groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/)

- You will need to install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) first.
- Add Stepping thread group in your Test Plan

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the relevant ramp-up period.

Given you have 500 users and you need 50 users to log in during 1 hour it means that

1. Each hour 25 users will log in
2. Your test duration will be 20 hours
3. Ramp-up period would be 20 hours as well

So it would be sufficient to use "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configured like:

[image]

More information: [JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)

Comment: thanks, where can i steup users/threads ? like 50 users , 100 users periodically ?